# File field is empty after JSON parsing on server but on client this field contains file

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, file-upload

I have a XMLHttpRequest:

```
chat.sendMessage = function (message) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", options["url"], true);
    console.log(message["image"]);
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(message));
};
```

As you see I log image field directly before sending message. And the log writes File object in a console. But on the server side this field is empty. Why?

This is a function where I attach image to image field:

```
imageAddWindowSubmit.onclick = function () {
    ...
    message.addImage(chatInputImage.files[0] || "");
    if (message["text"] || message["image"]) {
       chat.sendMessage(message);
    }
};
```

AddImage method:

```
this.addImage = function (image) {
    this.image = image;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form for uploading file.

If you can use jQuery then check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously) otherwise you have to add some code to handle file, check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#A_little_vanilla_framework)

Comment: Okey, thank you. I haven't a form. I decided to encode files to base64 and it's ok.